# What's the best way to hit the most targets in axe throwing?

Tags: rogue-legacy

One of the contests with the clown is to throw axes and break targets. I'm having trouble hitting enough of them. Is there a pattern that will allow me to make the most efficient use of my axes?

Comment: This is something i also wanted to ask but always forgot to do it. I do know that if you use Barbarian you can instantly destroy all of them with his special ability (that got fixed in patch though). Spellsword could have used his special ability to throw HUGE axes which also made it easy to clear, but that was also fixed with a patch.

Comment: Darn developers! Who do they think they are, fixing exploits and making the game better?! Grrr...

Comment: Since i didn't patch the game i can still use those exploits xD

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have not found a specific pattern, but there is a trick that helps. After you talk to the clown, you have the Axe and you can throw it to hit targets, but the game doesn't start counting your number of throws until AFTER you pass through the doorway into the target room.

Stand just outside the doorway to the target room, jump as high as you can and throw an axe. This will destroy several targets, but it doesn't count as one of your five throws. Then, enter the room and throw axes as normal.

My only other tip is to try to ensure your axe has a chance to hit targets both on the way up and on the way down. Also, you may need to jump just a little to make sure it hits the top row, but not too high or else you'll miss out on part of the axe's arc at the top as it goes over some targets.

Comment: I was able to destroy considerably more than several targets by doing this. This technique made it very, very easy.